# Ubuntu 13.04 amd64: libnm-glib problem

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit

I'm using a webstick part time for internet connection.

After several break ups of my provider, instead of getting a new connection, I get this answer:

```
Connection activation failed
(1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3' failed in libnm-glib.
```

Then I need to restart the whole thing, log out and log in alone would not cure this pest.

Any hint please available, thank you.

Comment: I've had this error since upgrading Ubuntu to 14.04. It happens when I try to connect to a new encrypted wifi access point. I can connect to ones I've already established in the past or unencrypted access points.